# Creating Enums Dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I am working on MVC project and  have One Enums Class in my model folder which is as follows :

```
    public class Enums
    {
    public enum eSiteName
    {

        [Description("Site 1")]
        Site_1 = 1,
        [Description("Site 2")]
        Site_2 = 2,
        [Description("Site 3")]
        Site_3 = 3
    }
  }
```

I want to create this enum from my database table. I have a table which is having this site data. I just want declaration in my Enums Class and implementation would be in my BaseController , How can this be done ?

Comment: Seems like a situation where you need to take a step back and ask yourself why would you want to? Just get the collection from the db and use the data that way, no need to manipulate it into some structure that it's not meant to be in.

Comment: if i don't create enums how would i maintain that structure through out the application ?

Comment: What structure are you trying to maintain?

Comment: this enum need to maintain so that can get database value anytime..

Comment: Exactly, so why make it an enum? An enum should be a static set of values you define in code. If you want something dynamic, just pull the table into it's own data structure when you need it.

Comment: why down vote ? I was not knowing feasibility of this.. this is not the way one should discourage the user

Comment: @ChrisSearles Your one sentence fixed a big confusion in my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me  like you try to mimic a table including relationships by using an enum.

Maybe a table named SiteNames with an Id:Int32 and a Description:String would fit better.